# Can I use a script to restore multiple SQL databases from .bak files?

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2012

I'm migrating 100 plus SQL databases over to a new server in a new location. I have the maintenance plan in place to take full back ups and then a script to copy over the `.bak` files to a temp directory. What I'm looking for is a way to mass restore those `.bak` files so that I don't have to spend all weekend doing it manually.

I found a decent stored procedure here : [SQL Restore](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jenss/archive/2011/09/08/bulk-backup-and-restore-at-the-tip-of-your-finger.aspx)

I put it in place and tested and I'm getting the following error:

> Msg 3118, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   The database "TF058" does not exist. RESTORE can only create a database when restoring either a full backup or a file backup of the primary file.
>   Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

I'm running SQL Server 2012 and the databases are in FULL recovery mode.

Comment: try asking on the DBAs site

Comment: Are you absolutely sure the bak file is a FULL backup?  The error seems to suggest that it is not.

Comment: To be certain i took a new full back up. Now when I run the sp it's trying to restore the file to the original data and log file paths instead of the new locations.

Comment: If you want to know how to restore 100+ backups efficiently, you will need to learn some kind of scripting language, like powershell or cmd line.  Regarding your error, i think you need to learn more about SQL Server's backup/restore syntax.  For that, go to msdn, look up "RESTORE DATABASE".  You'll see for your issue, you'll have to use the MOVE property.